# How to understand auto layout constraint's first item & second Item?

Tags: ios, autolayout

If I use a tableView as a View's subView in xib. And the tableView is fully covered the View. but in the xib's attributor , i can see the two vertical constrains just added : the 1st constraint use tableView's top as first Item , superView's top as second item  , But in the 2nd constraint, it show that superview's bottom was the first item , and the tableView's bottom was the second item . what is the reason of the xib to decide use who as the first item & second Item .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All constraints express a formula of the form:

```
firstItem.firstItemAttribute == secondItem.secondItemAttribute * multiplier + constant
```

(The relation could be `<=` or `>=`, too.)

Most often, the multiplier is 1, so drop that:

```
firstItem.firstItemAttribute == secondItem.secondItemAttribute + constant
```

It's usually easiest to think in terms of positive constants. So, something like:

```
view.Top == superview.Top + 20
```

makes sense. The view's top is 20 points below the superview's top. (In the coordinate system used by auto layout, Y increases down, so adding 20 points gives a position "below".)

You could switch the items around, but, if you want the same relationship, you'll need to negate the constant:

```
superview.Top == view.Top + -20
```

That -20 may make it harder to understand. By the way, Xcode will happily swap the two items and negate the constant for you. (If the multiplier weren't 1, the math gets a bit more complicated, but it's still possible.)

If you were to just swap the items around but not negate the constant, it would express a different relationship:

```
superview.Top == view.Top + 20
```

That would mean that the superview's top would be below the view's top. Or, rather, that the view would be positioned above the top of the superview and it's top would be clipped.

Now, constraints on the other end are most often expressed with items in the other order because you usually want the relationship to be the opposite. That is, you want the view's top to be below the superview's top, but you want the view's bottom to be **above** the superview's bottom. So, the constant is positive only when you arrange the items in the other order:

```
superview.Bottom == view.Bottom + 20
```

Comment: Great explanation, what about horizontal spacings? It has a default value of -16, `view.leading = superview.leading margin - 16`, seems to be not nature.

Comment: thx ,i thought the formula  "firstItem.firstItemAttribute == secondItem.secondItemAttribute * multiplier + constant " is use to calculate first item's frame based on secondItem's frame . So this formula will have nothing to do with the calculation of secondItem's frame, Am I right?

Comment: @gabbler: Horizontal works similarly to vertical: Leading is analogous to Top and Trailing is analogous to Bottom (because the coordinate system increases from Leading/Top to Trailing/Bottom). I'm not familiar with iOS and the margin stuff. If a view's Leading edge should be toward Trailing (usually rightward) from the superview's Leading, then it would typically be `view.Leading == superview.Leading + N`. However, if you express that same position relative to a margin, it would be `view.Leading = superview.Leading margin + (N - margin width)`. It may be that `(N - margin width)` is negative.

Comment: @ximmyxiao: No, you're not right. The formula is an equation, not an assignment. It's not "set firstItem.firstItemAttribute to be the result of …". It's "keep this equation true" or "keep firstItem.firstItemAttribute equal to …". That is symmetric. The system tries to find values for all of the attributes of all of the items that satisfies all of the constraints. Logically, it doesn't start with some values and work from those to compute the others. (The implementation may do something like that, at least provisionally, or it might not. I don't know.) The secondItem is constrained, too.

Comment: @KenThomases . I have one more question:If I set two labels (labelA ,labelB) with the equal width constraint，and labelA has more text (means this label should be wider) , so how did auto layout  choose which width will used for those two labels.(expand the labelB or shrink the labelA)

Comment: The labels each have a Content Hugging priority and a Compression Resistance priority. They also compute an intrinsic size based on their content. These become constraints like `labelA.width <=(@contentHuggingPrio) labelA.intrinsicWidth` and `labelA.width >=(@compressionResistPrio) labelA.intrinsicWidth`. Similar for labelB. These get resolved along with the rest of the constraints. As a practical matter, Compression Resistance is usually higher priority than Content Hugging, so the system prefers to "stretch" one label rather than compress the other.

Comment: @KenThomases thanks~~Now all my understanding about auto layout needs to be rebuilt (because I always thought that was a assignment before ),Do you know some material about How the auto layout system calc view's size and position based on constraints~:)

Comment: I don't really know of reading material other than Apple's own [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: @ Ken Thomases still, I have not got clear idea why it becomes negative and it has no effect on UI